# Pasting from external program into Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, copy, paste

Apologies if this has been answered - I just spent the last hour or so looking for a specific method and was unable to find it.

I am getting data from a reporting program via keyboard emulation with pynput - the program has specific menus for copying data and selecting what is actually copied.

I have managed to get the data copied to the clipboard, and have then called openpyxl to load my selected workbook. What I can not figure out how to do is how to select a specific cell and then paste the data that I've already copied starting at that cell.

The copy parameters from the reporting program copy the data in a way that will paste into Excel properly (cell by cell) so I know that it will not try and paste all the data into one cell. I just can't determine the proper method to select the cell and paste it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

As a side note, I'm INCREDIBLY new to python - I am well versed in VBA but I am trying to branch out so I apologize if I've stated anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the data already copied to the clipboard, you can use python pandas DataFrames to process it. Below is the method which accepts data copied from the clipboard and convert it into DataFrame.

```
pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+', **kwargs)
```

Now you can select whichever column you want from the DataFrame and using the to_csv method, you can write to the Excel file.

```
DataFrame.to_csv()
```

Check out the documentation :

read_clipboard() - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html

to_csv() - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
Sample Code :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was attempting to select the cell and use pyperclip to paste but it wasn't working.

Forgive me, but the parameters within the read brackets are for what?
Do I need to replace them with something?
I have a little regex knowledge but find myself a bit confused.

Comment: And since the columns parameter is optional, will ignoring it write all data?

Comment: read_clipboard() have the parameter as sep which specifies the separator, for say if your data is comma separated, give it as sep = ','.

Comment: about the to_csv() part, its gonna write the complete data if you do not specify the columns parameter. It you specify it for say columns =['a','b'], it will write only the a and b columns to csv.

Comment: Okay so, apologies, I'm just REALLY confused. Can you explain what is wrong here?
[CODE]
    import pandas
    from pandas import DataFrame

    data = pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+').values
    print(data)

[/CODE]
PLEASE forgive my stupidity - how in the hell do I denote code in this comment box.

Comment: check out the sample code in the answer. Don't think you are dumb. Asking questions is the sign of learning.

Comment: I've managed to get it to print out in the shell - when I attempt to write it to CSV it tells me that the 'str' object has no attribute 'columns' even though the printed output appears to be delimited by spaces and apostrophes

Comment: Paste your output and the error message in question.

Comment: Output looks like  
  
[['110618P' 'TILX305812' 1 ... nan 886577 '11/6/2018']

Error:  
File "*PATH to pandas formats*\csvs.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.has_mi_columns = (isinstance(obj.columns, MultiIndex) and
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: can you provide me the code, how you are writing it to csv.

Comment: I have managed to make this work:
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+').values
print(data)

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('SAMPLECARS.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

Comment: However, it removes the header row, and instead numbers both the columns and the rows

Comment: ok now I have managed to make it keep the first row by setting header=None, but it still creates both a column and a row with numbers

Comment: I have made it work finally with:
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+',header = None).values
print(data)

df = pandas.DataFrame(data) 

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('SAMPLECARS.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False, header = 0)
writer.save()